# REST controller in Symfony 2: how to deal with field names?

Tags: php, symfony

I just generated some entities and a CRUD using SensioGeneratorBundle on Symfony2 and i'm converting the generated CRUD to a REST API. I'm having problems with the field names... i wanted to have custom field names, while Symfony's bindRequest expects "acme_demobundle_tabletype_field" in order to work correctly and validate, i want to have just "field".

How can i POST with custom field names and make the controller understand and bind the correct values? For example:

POST

a: banana

b: chocolate

Symfony maps:

a => title

b => content

Comment: That I don't know. Closest I found is creating a custom [param converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two part to your question. First the prefix prepended to the fields name and the fields name themselves.

To get rid of the prefix, use the trick described by @m2mdas if you are on `2.1`. If your not on `2.1`, your best bet is to create your form using `createNamed` and give an empty name when creating the form. Something like this:

```
$this->formFactory->createNamed(new CustomType(), '', $data, $optionsArray);
```

Never tested this form in `2.0.x` but can confirm in `2.1` that having an empty name remove the field's prefix.

Where `formFactory` is an instance of the `FormFactory` service (`@form.factory`).

For the fields, you can use custom name and tell Symfony where it should map the property. For that, you use the `property_path` option. This will instruct symfony to map the property to this path instead of the default path. Here how you should use it in you form type when you define it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('a', 'text', array(
        'property_path' => 'title',
    ));

    $builder->add('b', 'text', array(
        'property_path' => 'content',
    ));
}
```

Using this, when Symfony received the field `a` from the POST data, it will map it to the property `title` and vice-versa when the form is rendered. Your object will need a `setTitle` method and a `setContent` method.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Amazing Matt, thanks a lot. I was almost getting rid of Forms on my REST controller and making validation by hand. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

I looked into github. According to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/7e7244ea53eb818716e98e753e1a33c6d372243d) PR, you can set empty parent name. So in your form type class just return empty string in `getName` method.

Comment: It says that my name is invalid. I'm returning ''.

Comment: Isn't there a way to have different field names and a custom mapping?